# cordova VS mozilla open web app

Tags: android, cordova, web-applications, mozilla, firefox-os

I'm working on the idea of a project that has to run as well online (via a remote server) and offline, on desktop (Linux/Mac OS X / Windows) and Firefox OS / Android mobile devices (Windows Phone and IOS is not a need).

This project have to be open, and I want to be as close to standards as possibles. I know a little about both Cordova and Mozilla Open Web App, and both seems to be really great on this aspects.

So, my question is : Which, between Mozilla Open Web App and Cordova, seams the closest to the future standards of web apps, and which can really respond to the need of running the app as well online and offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap is a good choice if you target only mobile devices: you would have been able to use their APIs to create Firefox OS as Android applications. Since you need to target all desktops, [Mozilla Open Web App](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS) is the choice.

By creating a Firefox OS applications, using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, you will of course have an application running on Firefox, but you will also be able to [run it on Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Open_web_apps_for_android) if you have Firefox installed. Last, but not least, you will be able to make the [application run on the desktop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Open_web_apps_for_desktop), again, by having Firefox installed.

As for the offline support on your application, you can either use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) or create [a packaged app](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Packaged_apps).

When it comes to the Web Standards, Firefox OS is using the standard you know. On top of that, [WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI) is available, so you can access to the hardware, and create a better experience with the platform. Those APIs are not part of the standard right now, but we are working with the W3C to make that happens. Note that if the standard change to something we did not have, we will make the change to be standard compliant.

P.S.: Full disclosure, I'm working for Mozilla.

Comment: Ok thanks, that confirm what I thought. Of course, I suppose you're totally neutral ;) Maybe you could answer to one other related question : what about the server side ? I suppose every solution could work, I'm just looking for the most logical choice. I was thinking about node.js, for performance and consistency ...

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, but Node.js is a good technology in my own opinion.